# Style suddenly does not show after no changes made to it, no error in the console or cmd

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

I am working with node.js, express and .ejs files. My style did work and i did not change anything about it before it stopped.
Here is the code:
https://github.com/RTweety/todoapp-v1/tree/main/todoapp-v1

I've checked the path and changed both it in the script.js and list.ejs but no response.

I also tried to restore the code to the point when it did work but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cloned Your Project and You have bug in `header.ejs` file.

Instead of this line

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
```

You should use  `<link/>` tag  like that and that's it ! :-)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
```

Here You have reference about How To link an external [stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)

---

**Folder and file structure *script.js*, *header.ejs*, terminal:**

[image]

---

**Output in browser**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It was originally this way but I changed the link tag due to a MIME type mismatch error which for some reason does not show up anymore. :)) Thanks again for your time.